# How can we add link_to with a div in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add `link_to` with a

```
<div class="panel-body">
```

it should be something like this

```
<%= link_to 'div',{:controller=>'users',:action=>'go'}
```

but I am not able to find any way.

This is my *div*:

```
<div class="panel-body"></div>
<div class="panel-footer back-footer pink">
  workers signup
</div>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can put a `div` inside of `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to users_path, :action => 'go' do %>
    <div>YOUR CONTENT</div>
<% end %>
```